# How to run concurrency in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, concurrency, python-telegram-bot

this is my code

```
import logging
import requests
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CallbackContext, CommandHandler

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Some code

async def complete(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # Some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('').build()

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start, block=False)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)

    register_handler = CommandHandler('register', register, block=False)
    application.add_handler(register_handler)

    complete_handler = CommandHandler('complete', complete, block=False)
    application.add_handler(complete_handler)

    application.run_polling()
```

For example I run /register hello, then run /complete bye, the complete command only run when the register command complete. I need the complete command will run immediate when I enter and don't wait the register command.

I checked the docs and wiki (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency) but still not work.

Please help me. Thanks

For example I run /register hello, then run /complete bye, the complete command only run when the register command complete. I need the complete command will run immediate when I enter and don't wait the register command.

Answer (score 1):

This question was also asked in the PTB support group: https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/661349
The [answer](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/661357) is that OP was using [blocking code](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/661359) in the callbacks (as the usage of the non-asyncio `requests` library indicates). PTB v20.x+ is build on `asyncio` and hence does not handle blocking code in terms of concurrency.

PS: Please don't ask the same question in mutliple places at once. When repeating a question somewhere because you didn't get a question in the other place yet, at the very least include links to all the places that you asked it at.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`